# Frequent kubernetes container restart

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, containers, v8

We are facing frequent `Kubernetes container restarts` in our `production env` and the container aborts by listing down below messages. In Kubernetes events, I also see a Backoff event.
Please find below the error msg log.

```
#
#
 1: 0xaef6f1  [node]
 3: 0xf5b8b9 v8::internal::GlobalBackingStoreRegistry::Register(std::shared_ptr<v8::internal::BackingStore>) [node]
 6: 0x7f268814b0ef  [/app/node_modules/ref-napi/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.node]
# Check failed: result.second.
#
10: 0xcd8cbb  [node]
 1: 0xaef6f1  [node]
 6: 0x7fecce5ef0ef  [/app/node_modules/ref-napi/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.node]
13: 0x14fa219  [node]
 7: 0x7fecce5f15bb  [/app/node_modules/ref-napi/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.node]

 

 8: 0x7fecce5f7ceb Napi::details::CallbackData<void (*)(Napi::CallbackInfo const&), void>::Wrapper(napi_env__*, 
12: 0xcda8e6 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]

 

#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffce56dd1e0
#
 5: 0xa36020 napi_get_typedarray_info [node]
 2: 0x1af81e4 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0xf5b8b9 v8::internal::GlobalBackingStoreRegistry::Register(std::shared_ptr<v8::internal::BackingStore>) [node]
#
Aborted (core dumped)
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffdae60ed30
11: 0xcda26c  [node]

 

 4: 0xc99a98 v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore() [node]

 

#
 9: 0xa2d08f  [node]
# Check failed: result.second.
10: 0xcd8cbb  [node]
 5: 0xa36020 napi_get_typedarray_info [node]
 2: 0x1af81e4 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
13: 0x14fa219  [node]
 7: 0x7f268814d5bb  [/app/node_modules/ref-napi/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.node]
# Fatal error in , line 0
 4: 0xc99a98 v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore() [node]
#
12: 0xcda8e6 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
#
Aborted (core dumped)
# Fatal error in , line 0
8: 0x7f2688153ceb Napi::details::CallbackData<void (*)(Napi::CallbackInfo const&), void>::Wrapper(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) [/app/node_modules/ref-napi/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.node]
 9: 0xa2d08f  [node]
11: 0xcda26c  [node]
```

I tried searching on the internet but was not able to find anything, some pointers would be really helpful here.

Answer (score 3):

Without more context this problem is hard to diagnose, but on a high level the answer is quite straight forward:
You have a nodejs based application that uses the ref-napi library for memory/buffer management. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ref-napi
Either you or a dependency is causing a problem related to native memory which lead to a crash of the node process.

Kubernetes notices that the container crashes and restarts it, to keep the pod available. Kubernetes is not to blame here, the application has a problem/bug and crashes. If this is fixed, the container restarts will stop.

Comment: To expand on this: with the provided data, the bug could be anywhere. I see two options: (1) Hoping that it may be fixed already, update all involved components (in particular, Node and any addons you're using). (2) Try to create a reproduction case, at least to learn more, ideally even one that you can share when you file a bug against ref-napi or Node or V8 or whichever component turns out to be a likely culprit.

Comment: Hi @Thomas we are using IBM MQ npm which has a `ref-napi` as a dependency.

Comment: The new question is: Why does it crash. It seems to use a native MQ driver. If you could provide a minimal reproducible test case, it would be fit for a separate SO question.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for your support, It seems that mq was creating multiple connections and due to the connection limit it was getting errored out. Hence this lead to termination of pod on errors.